# Spring Data JPA Hibernate OneToMany unidirectional getting duplicates in resultlist

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

can anyone help me with this problem?

I got a unidirectional OneToMany relation and getting duplicates in the result list.I'm using SpringDataJPA.

```
     @JoinTable(name = "previousTherapies_drugs",
     joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
     @JoinColumn(name ="drug_id")})
     private List<Drug> drugs;
```

How can i prevent these duplicates?
And where they came from?

> SOLVED:

I solved it, the problem was fetchtype was eager which is a join on the other table and produces duplicates.

now i am running with lazy and it works because there are 2 different sql statements fired.

thx

Comment: Please post the relevant code.